# Send devise confirmation email to new email instead of old email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable

By default devise sends confirmation email to **old** email if an email is changed.
In my case where a user is allowed to create an account via Twitter login, his initial email is blank since Twitter API does not give user's email. Later if user wants to **update** his email id, i want to send him confirmation email on **new** email id since his old email id is blank.

How can I achieve this in devise with confirmation email going to **new** email. I know its a security hole to send confirmation email to new email, but for now we can live with this issue .

Comment: Rightly said, a security hole. If you end up coding it manually you could at least ensure that this only happens when the old email is blank/nil. If not, stick with sending an email address to the old email.

Comment: Yes @rkon, we will ensure that it only happens when old email is blank. Any help with devise config for sending confirmation email to new email ?

Comment: Thoughts on asking a user for their email, when I they login via Twitter.  I have the code if you want it.

Comment: Thats a good suggestion @AndrewCharlesPotterKelley. We are asking user to enter his email, but the issue is : User record has already been created in database with email => nil & unconfirmed_email => nil. When we ask for email, the confirmation email was being sent to blank email id. I have posted my implemented solution in 3rd comment of 1st answer of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am manually calling

```
@user.send_confirmation_instructions
```

and changed the following line in mailer :

```
mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Confirm your email id")
```

to

```
mail(:to => user.unconfirmed_email, :subject => "Confirm your email id")
```

There was no need to remove the confirmable module from User model

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that this is something you can achieve via configuration.

To avoid altering the source code directly (not so maintainable) I would have an observer or a `before_save` on my `User` model.

If I detected an e-mail change I would take appropriate action (taking care of what I mentioned in my comment - not sending to the new email unless the old one is blank).

On a related note, have also a look in this SO question: [Devise, how to override send_confirmation_instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831419/devise-how-to-override-send-confirmation-instructions). Maybe it provides a cleaner way to do what you want.

Comment: even if I add observer,devise does not allow me to send_confirmation_instructions to new email. When I do @user.send_confirmation_instructions(:email =>@user.unconfirmed_email), it results in "wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)" error :(

Comment: what about disabling devise's auto confirmation sending and trigger it yourself once the new email has been saved in your User model?

Comment: I think I did it. Manually calling the @user.send_confirmation_instructions method and changing the line mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Confirm your email id") to mail(:to => user.unconfirmed_email, :subject => "Confirm your email id") in mailer worked. I will test it once more. There was no need to remove the confirmable module from User model.